# variable name from model to function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I would like to make a [function](/questions/tagged/function) on the basis of the `lm` results.

I make a model:

```
mod <- lm(log(speed)~dist + I(dist^2), data = cars)


names(summary(mod))
summary(mod)$coefficients[, 1]
```

and then I do a function that I want to use later

```
  calcVAL <-function(dist, mod) {
  df <- data.frame(value = summary(mod)$coefficients[, 1])
  df$var <- row.names(df)
  row.names(df) <- NULL
  print(df)

  df[1,1] + 
        df[2, 1] * dist +
        df[3, 1] * I(dist^2)
} 
calcVAL(10, mod)
```

what I want to do differently is that I want to replace the `dist` argument inside the `calcVAL` function that the function takes the name from the `df` that is created firstly in the function (similar to coefficient values) ex. name from a position `df[2, 2]`

```
                   value
(Intercept)  1.7729012293
dist         0.0311801430
I(dist^2)   -0.0001805469
```

like this

```
calcVAL <-function(dist, mod) {
  df <- data.frame(value = summary(mod)$coefficients[, 1])
  df$var <- row.names(df)
  row.names(df) <- NULL
  print(df)

  df[1,1] + 
        df[2, 1] * df[2, 2] +
        df[3, 1] * df[3, 2]             
} 
calcVAL(10, mod)
```

gives as expected the error

> Error in df[2, 1] * df[2, 2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: What does this mean??? *I want to replace the dist argument inside the calcVAL function that the function takes the name from the df that is created firstly in the function (similar to coefficient values) ex. name from a position df[2, 2]*

Comment: In this part of the code `exp(df[1,1] + 
        df[2, 1] * (dist))` I want that `dist` is taken from the `df$var`column in `df` as in my functions `dist` might be transformed

Comment: That name comes from the model object, not your function. So, do you want the model to be different? How do you want to call the function?

Comment: I want to call variable the name from the summary of the lm model as I do not want to type in a new variable name whenever I change the model